# Clone ubuntu system

Tags: clone

Is it possibe to clone a ubuntu system and is there any way to automatically replicate(sync) the changes made on a system(orginal) to another(replica) to use it as a backup?.Just like duplicate.

This should not effect the orginal ubuntu system.

Comment: What do you mean, replicate?  Are we talking configs?  All data on your hard drive?  Your home directory?

Answer (score 3):

You should try clonezilla http://clonezilla.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the linux command "dd" to clone your hard disk. Note that this will clone every byte of your disk, no matter if its "used" or not (thus, this is timeconsuming).

Then you could setup rsync to handle replication.

*Answer to the comment:*
rsync can synchronize files and folders both locally, and remotely over ssh. The syntax is straight forward: "rsync [OPTION...] SRC... [DEST]"

It would be easy to automate using CRON (man crontab).

Here is more information on rsync. http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html

Comment: How to use rsync to replicate with remote system and how to automate this?

Comment: I edited the answer to try to answer your comment.